# Swift - struct type does not conform to protocol

Tags: ios, swift

I am learning Swift, but I am bit stuck with the basics.. Downloaded a sample project from Apple but still not see what is the difference between these two:

My struct:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation

struct Store: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var categories: [Category]

    private var logoName: String
    var logo: Image {
        Image(logoName)
    }

    private var coordinates: Coordinates
    var locationCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(
            latitude: coordinates.latitude,
            longitude: coordinates.longitude)
    }

    struct Coordinates: Hashable, Codable {
        var latitude: Double
        var longitude: Double
    }
}
```

Sample:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation

struct Landmark: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var park: String
    var state: String
    var description: String
    var isFavorite: Bool

    private var imageName: String
    var image: Image {
        Image(imageName)
    }

    private var coordinates: Coordinates
    var locationCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(
            latitude: coordinates.latitude,
            longitude: coordinates.longitude)
    }

    struct Coordinates: Hashable, Codable {
        var latitude: Double
        var longitude: Double
    }
}
```

The first is failing with:

```
"Type 'Store' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'"
"Type 'Store' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'"
```

The second one is working properly.

What is the difference? Is there a settings somewhere in Xcode? :)

(The sample is from: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/handling-user-input)

Comment: What's `Category` It needs  to Equatable/Hashable, or you'll have to add the needed functions for `Store`. Ie, it can be by "default", if all its property are.

Comment: @Larme, funny I just answered basically exactly that and then saw your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Store` has a property that is an array of `Category`.  I would guess that `Category` does not conform to `Equatable` or `Hashable`, and so Swift cannot synthesize conformance.

`Landmark` contains properties that all conform to `Equatable` and `Hashable`, so it can synthesize conformance for `Landmark`.

There are two solutions to make `Store` conform.

1. Make `Category` conform to both protocols.  Then Swift could synthesize conformance for `Store`.
2. Explicitly implement the conformance for `Hashable` and `Equatable` for `Store` by implementing `static func == (lhs: Store, rhs: Store) -> Bool` and `func hash(into: inout Hasher)`

Depending on the implementation of `Category`, the simplest solution just might be:

```swift
extension Category: Hashable, Equatable { }
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you suggest a book or something to learn things like this?

Comment: I'm sure there are good books for Swift, but I haven't read any.  I came at Swift, I think it was version 2, and that was after 30+ years of C/C++, which meant I could transfer a lot of knowledge, and then follow evolution.  Paul Hudson's [Hackingwithswift.com](http://www.hackingwithswift.com) has a lot of good short intros to various Swift topics.  He also does videos on YouTube, including some "what's new in Swift" videos.  Watch WWDC videos.  Google Eric Sundell's blog.  Also periodically read through Swift.org.  Asks questions. But mostly just write code and fail a lot.

Comment: Also https://www.raywenderlich.com/ios/ (not as free as it once was, sadly)